# Get warning when using representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil

Tags: objective-c-blocks, nsdata, nsimage

I were trying to convert a image to NSData and got a below warning. Could you explain to me what is the warning, and how to fix it?

```
CGImageRef cgRef = [imgView.imageView image];
NSBitmapImageRep *newRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithCGImage:cgRef];
[newRep setSize:imgView.imageView.imageSize];
NSData *pngData = [newRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
```

warning for properties of representation:

> Null Passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Comment: Don't put `nil` and put a valid dictionary ?

Comment: Pass `@{}` instead of `nil`.